# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or one of its dependencies. When running chat bot C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, chatbot

I am trying to run my chat bot after I made some modifications within Visual Studio. My code works correctly when run locally with the bot framework emulator, but when published to my chat bot stored on Azure I get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Any help or insight into this problem would be much appriciated!

Comment: What is your Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version? Do you use Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs ?

Comment: The Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage is version 9.3.1, and I do not have Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs installed in my project should I?

Answer (score 2):

Open nuget console and paste in to install the missing package:

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 9.3.1
```

Comment: So this didn't resolve the issue, I also tried to paste:       `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.3.1.0" newVersion="9.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Into the Web.Config but still get the same error

Comment: Actually this line: "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference." Means that the dll version is different that referenced dll version.

Comment: So how do I find which dll version is currently running in the azure code? or if it is an older version how do I update it?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove this from the web config file.**

`<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.3.1.0" newVersion="9.3.1.0" />       </dependentAssembly>`

Remove these lines from the web config file and then rebuild your application.